# Как с помощью ffmpeg разрезать каждый видеофайл по середине и эти 2 части поменять местами?

Tags: ffmpeg

В папке C:\test лежат несколько видеофайлов (более 10шт.),

Все файлы разных форматов:

- mkv
- avi
- mp4

Все файлы произвольной длинны.

Как с помощью ffmpeg разрезать каждый видеофайл по середине на 2 части и эти 2 части переставить местами, а далее сохранить получившийся видеофайл в том же формате что и у исходного файла.
И сделать тоже самое нужно для каждого файла в папке C:\test ?

Comment: Если без перекодирования, то точно посередине вряд ли получится, потому что резать можно только по ключевым кадрам (но можно примерно посередине - по ближайшему ключевому кадру). С перекодированием можно точно посередине, но это снизит качество

Comment: дело в том что все видео имеют разную продолжительность. и даже не принципиально чтоб разделение было прям точно по середине.